# Basic authentication form works for /myapp/index.jsp but not for /myapp/?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, web, war

(I'm using WebSphere 7, by the way)

I have a java web app with basic auth and a security constraint configured (show below).

When I visit my web app at `http://localhost:9080/myapp/`, the auth form does not appear.

However, when I visit the page directly `http://localhost:9080/myapp/index.jsp` the auth form does appear.

How can I make the form appear for the `/` welcome page?

```
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
    <url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>
    <http-method>GET</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint>
    <role-name>USERGROUP1</role-name>
  </auth-constraint>
  <user-data-contraint>
    <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
  </user-data-contraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a dummy index.jsp that forwards to your "real" index page.

Comment: Thx.  Forward didn't work, but redirect did.  Just FYI, here's my index.jsp `<% response.sendRedirect("main.jsp"); %>`

Answer (score 2):

try going from this   `<url-pattern>/index.jsp</url-pattern>`

to this   `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

Comment: Thx. Now I get prompted to log it for `/` but `/index.jsp` is unprotected. :)

Comment: Ok -- looks like `/*` did the trick.  However, now everything is protected.  Is there a way for me to explicitly unprotect `login.jsp` and `logout.jsp` pages so I can move from BASIC to FORM based authentication?

Comment: I do not know about an exclude policy, but what I do is have /myapp/* protected and /login free of authentication. You don't want /logout out of your authentication scheme.

Comment: Excellent approach.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I particularly don't use the tomcat authentication, I control by myself the security so I do not depend in the appserver. Now, I have a product and I live with it, if you are doing just a project, is the right way to go with tomcat native auth.